# CORS not working in my MVC app. Getting Header error despite settings web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-headers, cors

I am getting the following error when trying to make a CORS request to my MVC app.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.ASite.com/gallery/cors/0. Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. 11576?EventId=3108:1
error: Server responded with 0 code.
```

I have added the following custom headers to my web.config which I thought was supposed to allow CORS requests. Can someone please help.

> ```
> <httpProtocol>
>   <customHeaders>
>     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
>     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
>     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT" />
>   </customHeaders>
> </httpProtocol>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matthew's answer glances off the main issue. You cannot use `*` in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` [per the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header). You have to specify the exact headers you want to allow.

If there are a lot of headers which change, you may want to look into a server side script to read the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` HTTP request header, then add the correct headers to the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response.

Comment: For sure. I wanted to add the code that would get it working for Julian. Your explanation is more complete so have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Your web.config is specifying to allow all headers.  You should specify only what you need:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
```