# Cors requests and MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-headers, cors

So I have a view on a controller ...

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("MyView")]
public ActionResult MyView()
{
    // first attempt at solving problem
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");

    return PartialView();
}
```

I tried adding this attribute (2nd attempt) ...

```
public class AllowCors : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

As im using owin to initialise my app I figured this might work (3rd attempt) ...

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "*" });
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] { "*" });
        return context.Response.WriteAsync("handled");
    }

    return next.Invoke();
}).UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PreHandlerExecute);
```

The problem is that if I just straight up ask for it by putting the url in the browser I get the right headers ...

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

... moving over in to postman to test this, when I issue an OPTIONS call to the same URL I get this in the headers ...

```
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
```

... so how do I get MVC to respond correctly to the OPTIONS http verb so that I can use this view outside the domain of the site?

**EDIT**

it's worth noting that I have looked around already and found all these and many more ...

[The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352519/the-requested-resource-does-not-support-http-method-options?lq=1)

[jQuery $.ajax(), $.post sending "OPTIONS" as REQUEST_METHOD in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099787/jquery-ajax-post-sending-options-as-request-method-in-firefox)

[AJAX in Chrome sending OPTIONS instead of GET/POST/PUT/DELETE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783079/ajax-in-chrome-sending-options-instead-of-get-post-put-delete)

[Why does this jQuery AJAX PUT work in Chrome but not FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705366/why-does-this-jquery-ajax-put-work-in-chrome-but-not-ff)

[How to support HTTP OPTIONS verb in ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095777/how-to-support-http-options-verb-in-asp-net-mvc-webapi-application)

... i'm also very familiar with using CORS and making CORS requests in to WebAPI, but for some reason I can't seem to make a CORS request in to MVC without getting this seemingly "dummy" response back.

I think what I need is a means to override / replace the MVC default behaviour to this HttpVerb based request to allow me to embed views in a remote site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install these two nuget packages:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Cors
Microsoft.Owin.Cors
```

Then in your `Startup.cs` add this line inside the `Configuration` function:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    }
}
```

In my demo setup I'm sending a post request from the domain http://example.local (Apache) to the domain http://localhost:6569/ (IIS Express).

Without `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);` (notice the warning in the console and no CORS headers):

[image: before setting up CORS]

And after adding the packages and adding the line to the `Configuration` method:

[image: After setting up CORS]

As you can see in the screenshot, the `access-control-allow-origin` was added in the response headers as expected/

Comment: Dang, I was really hoping it would be that simple but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Darth_Wardy Just created a new project to test it out and it works as expected. Are you sure there's nothing else messing up with your setup?

Comment: Hmmm, odd, this isn't what i'm seeing ... time for some old school comment out style debugging ... the only other stuff I have going on right now is identity framework.

Comment: Here's my startup: https://gist.github.com/TehWardy/b36b2cdf851ddb80c8cdb52c51c6d24f ... any ideas?

Comment: Also my MVC config: https://gist.github.com/TehWardy/639494577863f6e29cac6d9445b6b2bd

Comment: I'm not doing a POST, i'm doing a GET for a html view ... wonder if that makes some sort of difference

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference since I tried both and they worked. I'm thinking that it might be ninject but I don't know enough about it.

Comment: Hmmm, I wondered that too, IoC can be a bit of a hell hole if you do complex stuff, so I commented that out and got the same result :( ... maybe its something about my machine / VS / my project file ... in some way ... this is just plain wierd ... i'm gonna +1 your answer because its clearly a good answer.

Comment: Hmm odd, I had to also add the config elements (for some reason) as per this question and its answer ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245831/cors-not-working-in-my-mvc-app-getting-header-error-despite-settings-web-config ... please add this to your answer but i'll give you the tick anyway :) ... thanks for the time on this one @Nasreddine

Comment: I'm on mobile and I don't want to mess up the formatting of my question but I'll make sure to add them one I'm on my computer again. Glad to see that you finally solved your problem.